# How do I remove duplicate records

Tags: sql, oracle

Query:

```
Select table_c.id_number, table_c.name, table_s.site_name,table_co.Contract_name 
FROM table_c , table_s, table_m, table_o, table_a, table_con 
  WHERE 
   table_s.objid = table_c.sobjid
   AND table_m.cobjid (+) = table_c.objid 
   AND table_o.objid (+) = table_m.olobjid   
   AND table_a.objid (+) = table_o.aobjid 
   AND table_co.objid (+) = table_a.conobjid;
```

Here I have 6 tables. table_c and table_s have one 2 one relationship. It is possible that for 1 table_o record, we can have 2 table_c records or may be no record.Since I need to take table_co values in SELECT along with table_c and table_s tables,  I used left out join on all tables table_c->table_m->table_o->table_a->table_co.

Now on running this query it gives me duplicate records. I have millions of records in table_c so if i use distinct or Union ALL to remove duplicate records, my query takes very long time and this is not acceptable solution.

Can I right this query in such a way that it gives me unique records without performance issue.

Please note, this query is part of a sql view is used by external systems to get data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please rewrite your query using explicit join syntax.

Comment: I agree with tim join syntax would make this easier to troubleshoot as your relatiionships are not clear. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp is an article on inner join in case that is a newr concept.  The one issue I see right away is you have no relationship defined for table_s to the other tables which would mean that will create a cross join and likely return a ton of duplicates which is probably also why distinct or group by performance would be poor.

Comment: Hi @Matt/@Tim, I also agree with suggestion to use explicit join (Inner/left outer join) and re-write the query. Another point, I don't think table_s can be reason of duplicate records as it has one2one relation with table_c and table_c is a leading table in this query.  Thanks-

Answer (score 1):

Try using `ROW_NUMBER()` :

```
SELECT * FROM (
    Select table_c.id_number, table_c.name, table_s.site_name,table_co.Contract_name ,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY table_c.id_number,table_c.name ORDER BY 1) as rnk
    FROM table_c 
    INNER JOIN table_s ON(table_s.objid = table_c.sobjid)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table_m ON(table_m.cobjid = table_c.objid )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table_o ON(table_o.objid = table_m.olobjid)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table_a ON(table_a.objid = table_o.aobjid )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table_con ON(table_co.objid = table_a.conobjid))
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Notes: Please avoid the use of implicit join syntax(comma separated) and use the proper syntax of a join.

I used `PARTITION BY table_c.id_number,table_c.name` , add all the columns specify a 'unique' row.

Comment: The legacy join syntax is not incorrect - it is just confusing.

Comment: I might have chosen the wrong word,that's not what I meant. I guess proper would have been better @MT0

Comment: Hi @Sagi, I tried your solution and here is outcome:  1) If I provide filter condition e.g table_c.id_number='12345' then it does not give me duplicate record.  2) If i don't apply any filter then query take too much time in giving initial set of records.  So I believe still we have performance issue.  Thanks

Comment: Any more suggestions please?